# Single web server and ETags

Tags: etag

Does anyone know if it is worth disabling ETags on an web application that is hosted on a single web server? Currently we don't make use of ETags in our application.

If it is worth disabling them - why?

Many thanks.

Comment: For me this sounds like a wrong question: ETags are used for implementing optimistic locking (i.e. one type of concurrency control). IMHO the need for concurrency control doesn't depend on the number of hosts.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this helps, but you can read about etags here:
http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/07/high_performanc_11.html

and here is [what Jeff Atwood thinks](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000932.html) about ETags:

> ETags are a checksum field served up
>   with each server file so the client
>   can tell if the server resource is
>   different from the cached version the
>   client holds locally. Yahoo recommends
>   turning ETags off because they cause
>   problems on server farms due to the
>   way they are generated with
>   machine-specific markers. So unless
>   you run a server farm, you should
>   ignore this guidance. It'll only make
>   your site perform worse because the
>   client will have a more difficult time
>   determining if its cache is stale or
>   fresh. It is possible for the client
>   to use the existing last-modified date
>   fields to determine whether the cache
>   is stale, but last-modified is a weak
>   validator, whereas Entity Tag (ETag)
>   is a strong validator. Why trade
>   strength for weakness?

also [interview with Steve Souders](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?showNum=390) at .NET Rocks may help:

> **Steve Souders**:  ... the  default implementation of
>   IIS and Apache, they put  both of
>   those servers, put something in the
>   e-tag that  will make it very likely
>   that if the user ever has to  check
>   the validity of that resource, the
>   browsers are  going to be incorrectly
>   told that the resource is no  longer
>   valid.  So in Apache’s case, what they
>   put in  the e-tag is the INO number of
>   the file on that web  server so that
>   if you have more than one web servers 
>   hosting your site which most large
>   websites do, that  INO number is never
>   going to match across two  servers so
>   if yesterday the user went to server
>   one  and today they tried to validate
>   that resource and they  go to server
>   2, the e-tag is not going to match,
>   e-tag  overrides last modified date so
>   instead of just  returning a 200-byte
>   304 response, the server has to 
>   return a 50k response of the entire
>   image.

Comment: I would give you +10 if I could for providing both of the resources which I wanted to give :-)

Answer (score 0):

"If you’re hosting your website on one server, it isn’t necessary to remove ETags. The same ETag will be used every time and the validation check will take place efficiently and correctly."

Source: [Dean Hume](http://deanhume.com/Home/Index)